# Using wp_insert_post() for custom post type posts are saved but uneditable

Tags: wordpress

Hello I have made a PHP script for wordpress that insert new posts using a custom type via wp_insert_post.
Using the code above I can get the post saved but i can't edit it using the admin panel. I'm wondering why? can anybody help me?

```
$post = array(
  'comment_status' =>  'closed',
  'post_author' => 1,
  'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
  'post_content' => $postdata['name'],
  'post_status' => 'publish', 
  'post_title' => strtoupper(strip_tags($postdata['name'])), 
  'post_type' => 'xCustom' // custom type


);  

 wp_insert_post($post);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress converts all custom post type slugs to lowercase, so instead of using:

```
'post_type' => 'xCustom'
```

You should be using:

```
'post_type' => 'xcustom'
```

I just spent 3 hours troubleshooting this on my own site.